# How to find PDF value from histogram plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have the following histogram plot in MATLAB:-

[image]

I have calculated the occurrence for each container (approximate,) probability for each container (approximate,) and the width of each container from the histogram plot.

I am not sure how can I use these parameters to find the estimate value of  probability density function (PDF.)

Could someone please tell me which formula should I use to calculate the PDF using these parameters?

Comment: I have found a post. Probably It can be helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/a/497886/748015

Answer (score 1):

The histogram is a good numerical estimate for the PDF sampled a the bin centers. Just scale it so that the sum over all bins is 1.

The quality of the estimate depends on number of samples and "good" choice of the bins. The latter one is a trade off: smaller bins give you better amplitude resolution and wider bins make the PDF in each band more accurate.

In your case this looks fairly uniformly distributed. The two outer bins are lower than the rest which could be real, but it could also be caused by the bins extending past the max and the min of a signal. It's important how to line up the bins with the min, mean & max of the signal.